# notification intent opens the apps main activity in background if its paused

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have a notification service running that will create a notification for the user and if the user clicks the notification it opens an activity to display the message, the method I am using to create the notification is :

```
public void createNotificationMsg(String name,String doing, boolean persistent){

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),
            0, new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MessageNotificationActivity.class)
                    .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
                            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP).putExtra("message", doing),
            PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);


    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            (NotificationCompat.Builder) new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.my_logo_96)
                    .setContentTitle(name)
                    .setContentText(doing)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL)
                    .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                    .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                    .setColor(Color.parseColor("#1aadce"));

    if (persistent){
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(true);
    }
    else {
        notificationBuilder.setOngoing(false);
    }

    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(getApplicationContext());

    Notification notification = notificationBuilder.build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
}
```

the MessageNotificationActivity is using the "android:style/Theme.Dialog" to make it look like a dialog now the thing is that when I click on the notification everything goes well and the activity is opened like a dialog with nothing in the background but if the app is paused and is in background when I click the notification it brings the apps Main activity to the front and then opens the MessageNotiicationActivity on top of it. How can I make the notification not bring the main activity to front and only intent to the specefied activity?

Answer (score 1):

The reason this happens is that your dialog-themed Activity has the same **"task affinity"** as the other activities in your app, so when you click on the notification, Android looks for an appropriate task in which to launch the dialog-themed Activity. If your app is in the background, Android will see it as a task with the same **"task affinity"** as the dialog-themed Activity and bring that task to the foreground and launch the dialog-themed Activity into that task.

To prevent this from happening, you need to add `android:taskAffinity=""` to the `<activity>` declaration in the manifest for your dialog-themed Activity. This tells Android to launch the dialog-themed Activity into a new task, and not into your app's task.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK to your intent. This will clear any other activities in the task.