# what context should i use to show custom notification when my app is in background

Tags: android, service, notifications, dialog, android-alertdialog

I have an android application. I have a background service running on a worker thread. My app is in background (home key pressed). Some message came to the service worker thread. Now i want to show the content of this message on dialog . Since my app is in background ,what context should i use to show this dialog. I mean this dialog should be shown on any screen , may be some other app's screen .Because my app is in background and user might be using some other app , and meanwhile the message came to service thread. So it should be shown on the top of the other application

Comment: You will need `app Overlay` permission from user to get your dialog shown.

Comment: Push notifications are designed for this one. No need to reinvent the wheel. Users will dislike your app, if some unwanted dialogs will appear during app is in background.

Comment: Use WidowManager and create an overlay and add your view in that. Use this URL for reference https://gist.github.com/bjoernQ/6975256
and as Michal_196 says you need app overlay permission for that

Comment: you need to create a dialog theme activity and from your service you can call your dialog themed activity from where you will have context of that activity.

Comment: @NorthernPoet my app is for offline messaging , i do not use push notifications.

Comment: @PardeepKumar, general notifications is fine, https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html?hl=en

Comment: @ Pradeep please have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39691342/5308778)