# Flutter app display message in another app

Tags: android, flutter

I want to display a msg box when another app is launched. The msg can be changed in a Flutter app. So this last one got to be responsible for displaying. It would run in the background. Any ideas?

This is part of a learning experience for Flutter. So, so far the technologies that was tried is basic Flutter

Answer (score 2):

Flutter uses a different rendering canvas as compared to what native apps use. I don't think it is possible to display a message box or `AlertDialog` using Flutter's own rendering on top of another app. The only way I see in order to do this is implementing a platform-specific functionality.

For Android, you can use a `BroadcastReceiver` to check the app that have been launched. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479508/show-dialog-activity-over-another-app-from-background).

Comment: Yeah, it was my line of thinking as well(platform specific functionality). Will check the link. Thanks a lot.