# Unable to add window -- token null even use TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT

Tags: android

i can't show draw over another app via service even after the window has TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT type, my code :

```
    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
            4,
            4,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ALERT,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL
                    | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
            PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

    WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View myView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.floating_view, null);
    myView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Log.e("click", "touch me");
            return true;
        }
    });

    // Add layout to window manager
    wm.addView(myView, params);
```

and i already enable the permission :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTION_MANAGE_OVERLAY_PERMISSION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" />
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5796611/dialog-throwing-unable-to-add-window-token-null-is-not-for-an-application-wi doesn't help

Comment: May be this will also help https://stackoverflow.com/a/39691342/3894930

Comment: are you use it's because of your code ?

because i just try that code in service, and it's working fine

Comment: do you get any errors from logcat when this code runs?