# How to show the Custom Dialogue over the another app

Tags: android, kotlin, android-dialog

I am developing an app which is using the share function. When someone share the link from any app need to show some alert/dialogue for better user experience without opening my app.

Example - Sharing the video from youtube it opens a small dialogue which shows that link is successfully shared with Ok button. when click on button, dialogue dismiss and i again use the youtube app.

I followed instructions from this link but not able to achieve the results
[Show dialog activity over another app from background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479508/show-dialog-activity-over-another-app-from-background)

[This is what i am trying to achieve in my app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ko2Z1.png)

Comment: ` When someone share the link from any app`? Can you be more specific with your question . also add the code what you have tried and what exactly is not working .

Comment: @ADM, Please check now. i added an image of the view which i am trying to achieve. Thanks

Comment: If your app has the Share privilege then just make the Share Activity a transparent . I don't think it will be a problem .