# Android Floating Action Button in foreground over other Apps?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-alertdialog, overlay

I'd need an simple example of an translucent activity or something like that to make a button of my own app appear in front of all other things on the device for **current** android versions? Is this still possible? I tried different solutions from stack overflow, but none seem to fit to the nowadays versions.

I'd like to display a small text or a badge also in this way.

Comment: "I tried different solutions from stack overflow, but none seem to fit to the nowadays versions" -- perhaps you could provide a [mcve] explaining what you tried and what problems you encountered. This form of UI is likely to go away, and already is greatly restricted on some devices, for security concerns. The long-term solution is Android's "bubbles" system.

Comment: I would! But they are old and they are long, so... look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top) or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39479508/show-dialog-activity-over-another-app-from-background)... so not knowing what's up to date, doesn't make much sence to go trough all that... I' need at least the possibility to get a click through my app.

Comment: Those links are nice... but you do not explain why they are unsuitable for your use or what problems you ran into when trying to use them. In other words, what makes your question different from those questions? "so not knowing what's up to date" -- Stack Overflow answers have dates on them. Some of the answers are fairly recent.

Comment: That it just didn't work... or I was too stupid for them - so I needed a more simple example.

Answer (score 0):

I think can use [Bubbles](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/bubbles) just like this:

> [image]
> [image]